# How to handle prototypes when saving knockout functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I got this object Message. On Message I have a prototype `"toggleLike"`.
Liking/unliking works pretty well until I save my message. Then I get an error:

> "TypeError: this.isLikedByMe is not a function"

referring to the line `this.isLikedByMe(!this.isLikedByMe());` (see below).

However putting  `"toggleLike"` as an attribute (function) to the object works nice.

But why does the prototype cause this error?

Here´s my code:

```
Message = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.messageID = data.messageID;
    self.messageText = ko.observable(data.messageText);
    self.isLikedByMe = ko.observable(data.isLikedByMe || false);

    // //this works
    // self.toggleLike = function(){
    //     self.isLikedByMe(!self.isLikedByMe());
    // };

    return self;
};
Message.prototype.toggleLike = function () {
    this.isLikedByMe(!this.isLikedByMe());
};

viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.myMessage = ko.observable( 
        new Message({
            messageID: -1, 
            messageText: 'This is an example' 
        })
    );

    self.likeThisMessage = function (data) {
        data.toggleLike();
        // some more code
    };

    self.sendMessage = function (data) {
        var newmsg = new Message({
                            ID: -1,
                            messageText: self.myMessageText(),
                         });
        self.saveMessage(newmsg);
    };

    self.saveMessage = function (msg) {
        if (msg.ID == -1) {
            //ajax insert
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceRoot + "InsertMessageItem",
                beforeSend: serviceFramework.setModuleHeaders,
                data: msg,
                cache: false
            });
            // handle returndata and update msg.ID to value from db.
        }
        else {
            // update ...
        }
    };
}; // viewModel ends
```

HTML:

```
 <ul data-bind="with: myMessage">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text:messageText"><br/>
        <a href="#self" data-bind="visible: !toggleLike(), click:$root.likeThisMessage">Like</a> 
        <a href="#self" data-bind="visible: toggleLike(),click:$root.likeThisMessage">Unlike</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: shouldn't this be 'this.isLikedByMe = ! this.isLikedByMe' ?

Comment: Your question's code is rather hard to follow, there's quite a few bits needed to reproduce your problem. Please update the question so we can repro the issue (it also helps if you strip out the things *not* needed for the repro, e.g. the `ajax` bit). Preferably use a runnable stack snippet or other type of fiddle for support.

Comment: @Jeroen Do you get points from all your down-voting? What is it you don´t understand?

Comment: @AsleG Can you provide the HTML for this? will help a lot

Comment: No, I don't get points for downvoting. It's just an honest attempt to indicate the question currently isn't really understandable (I usually check back to see if the OP has edited, and change votes accordingly). What I don't understand is how you get the error you quote with the code you posted. You should probably check [this guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because the code you posted [will *not* reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/993Lcjkp/2/), not even [if I try to stub out things you've omitted](http://jsfiddle.net/993Lcjkp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

While your question is incomplete, I'm going out on a limb here and guess: you use `toggleLike` in a binding, such as

```
<button data-bind="click: myMessage.toggleLike">Like</button>
```

The problem is not that you are using a function defined on a prototype, or that the prototype function calls another function defined in the constructor — all that works fine.

The problem is that you are executing `toggleLike` with the wrong `this`. In Javascript, you can "borrow" functions from an object and execute them in a totally different context, meaning with a different `this` inside them:

```
var Mary = function Mary() {
  this.name = 'Mary';

  this.sayName = function sayName() {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
  };
};

var Sue = function Sue() {
  this.name = 'Sue';
};

var mary = new Mary(),
    sue  = new Sue();

mary.sayName.call(sue);
// executes Marys `sayName` with `this` set to `sue`
```

In Knockout, this can happen accidentally, often in `click` bindings. In the above binding example:

```
<!-- we assume that $data here is your viewmodel -->
<button data-bind="click: myMessage.toggleLike">Like</button>
```

what really happens on click is that Knockout "borrows" `toggleLike` from myMessage, and executes it with `this` set to `$data` — your viewmodel:

```
Message.prototype.toggleLike = function () {
  // `this` is now your viewmodel, which does not have `isLikedByMe`
  this.isLikedByMe(!this.isLikedByMe());
};
```

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to avoid this:

```
<button data-bind="click: myMessage.toggleLike.bind(myMessage)">Like</button>
```

Another way is to make sure that `$data` is the object you are trying to call the function on:

```
<!-- ko with: myMessage -->
    <button data-bind="click: toggleLike">Like</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

works just as well.

Comment: Thanx @janfoeh ! That was a good explanation. Appreciate it.
how would you used the .bind(message) if message was an item in a foreach-loop?   (i.e  <ul data-bind="foreach: messages"><li><button data-bind="click: toggleLike.bind(????)"</li></ul>

Comment: @AsleG in a `foreach` loop you shouldn't need that — the loop behaves just like `with:` in that regard, because inside the loop, `$data` is already the right object. As a rule of thumb: when you can call the function directly, such as `toggleLike`, you're fine. When you have a dot somewhere, such as `myMessage.toggleLike`, you have to be careful.

Comment: in my code I don´t call toggleLike directly, I call a function ($root.likeClick). In likeClick I do: data.toggleLike(). That should be fine, no? 
(The reason for this function is I need some more logic in there).

Comment: Does it work? Then it's fine :) I suggest familiarizing yourself with your browsers' debugger — they make stuff like this _so much_ easier. Instead of guessing, you can simply set a breakpoint on the code in question and actually _see_ what `this` or other variables are. Set aside just 30 minutes to read through and try https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging, and I promise you that writing Javascript will never be the same.

Comment: Crome better than Firebug you reckon?

Comment: Might be a matter of taste, but for me, yes. It's the one thing keeping me on Chrome.